# how can I put array inside class

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to put array inside class

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

                item_messages.add(new Item_Messages(response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("id"),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("userid"),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("authorname"),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("message"),String.valueOf(response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getJSONArray("Likes").length()),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("type"),list.get(0)));
```

but there is a problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJyhp.png)

my class

```
package com.salah.mymessages.whatsapp;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Item_Messages {


    String id,userid,authorname,message,likes,type;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Item_Messages(String id, String userid, String authorname, String message, String likes, String type, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.authorname = authorname;
        this.message = message;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.type = type;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

hope you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
package com.salah.mymessages.whatsapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Item_Messages {


String id,userid,authorname,message,likes,type;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Item_Messages(String id, String userid, String authorname, String message, String likes, String type, List<String> list) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.authorname = authorname;
    this.message = message;
    this.likes = likes;
    this.type = type;
    this.list = list;
    }
}
```

And this

```
item_messages.add(new Item_Messages(response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("id"),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("userid"),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("authorname"),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("message"),String.valueOf(response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getJSONArray("Likes").length()),response.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(x).getString("type"),list));
```

The last parameter in constructor need a List and you put the first String from the list `(list.get(0))`

Comment: I can use ArrayList<ItemLikes> list = new ArrayList<>(); inside Item_Messages  Class or I can't?

Comment: but if I used ArrayList<ItemLikes> list = new ArrayList<>(); inside class Item_Messages how I can use him in adapter recyclerview you have any example :)